# Asp panel Vertical scroll bar always visible

Tags: asp.net

I have created asp web page with asp panel as bellow

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server" ScrollBars="Horizontal">
</asp:Panel>
```

In IE Browser(8,9,10) it will always enable vertical scroll bars but Firefox is only show horizontal scroll bar.

In here I need only Horizontal scroll bars how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this. It's a  HTML 5 property so it may work in modern browsers.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server" style="overflow-x:scroll;">
```